# JavaScript animated counter with fixed number of decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery

I downloaded a jQuery animated number counter. It counts from `0` to infinity normally, but now I want to count from `0.0000` to infinity. However, I discovered that when it gets to `0.01223`, it extends to `0.12239999999999` and keeps increasing.

I want it to be fixed to `0.0000`. That's all.

```js
$('#counter-block').ready(function() {
  $('.fb').animationCounter({
    start: 0,
    step: 1,
    delay: 100
  });
  $('.bike').animationCounter({
    start: 0.0100,
    step: 0.00005,
    delay: 2200,
    txt: ' BTC'
  });
  $('.code').animationCounter({
    start: 0,
    end: 570,
    step: 4,
    delay: 1000
  });
  $('.coffee').animationCounter({
    start: 490,
    end: 1560,
    step: 20,
    delay: 900,
    txt: ' cl'
  });
});

(function($) {
  $.fn.animationCounter = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      try {
        var element = $(this);
        var defaults = {
          start: 0,
          end: null,
          step: 1,
          delay: 1000,
          txt: ""
        }
        var settings = $.extend(defaults, options || {})
        var nb_start = settings.start;
        var nb_end = settings.end;
        element.text(nb_start + settings.txt);
        var counter = function() {
          // Definition of conditions of arrest
          if (nb_end != null && nb_start >= nb_end) {
            return;
          }
          // incrementation
          nb_start = nb_start + settings.step;
          // display
          element.text(nb_start + settings.txt);
        }
        // Timer
        // Launches every "settings.delay"
        setInterval(counter, settings.delay);
      } catch (e) {
        alert(e + ' at line ' + e.lineNumber);
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div class="intro">
    <h1 class="title-plugin">animationCounter.js</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="block-wrapper">
    <div class="block">
      <p><span class="lnr lnr-heart"></span></p>
      <p class="counter-wrapper"><span class="fb"></span></p>
      <p class="text-block">like</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <p><span class="lnr lnr-code"></span></p>
      <p class="counter-wrapper"><span class="code"></span></p>
      <p class="text-block">code</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <p><span class="lnr lnr-bicycle"></span></p>
      <p class="counter-wrapper"><span class="bike"></span></p>
      <p class="text-block">bicycle</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <p><span class="lnr lnr-history"></span></p>
      <p class="counter-wrapper"><span class="coffee"></span></p>
      <p class="text-block">coffee</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>Copyright (c) 2017 <a href="http://www.pixel-renaissance.com">Micheline Pavadé</a></p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

If I refresh the page the number starts from `0` back again. Is there a way to make it continue the counting even if the user closes the page?

Comment: "If I refresh the page the number starts from 0 back again. Is there a way to make it continue the counting even if the user closes the page?" do you want to **save the value** or **continue the counting**??

Comment: i want to continue the counting while the user is sleeping or logs out

Comment: You need a back end language with a database to store data in

Comment: I think thats if i want to save the value, to continue the counting i think it should be done on a client side

Comment: By "sleeping or logs out" do you include closing the browser? If so then yes you definitely need a back end execution, there's no way for a client side code to run if the client is not on! Javascript is a frontend / client side language it only runs on the page you visit. If you close there is not more JS

Comment: Ok but even if the user closes the browser can the number keep counting?

Comment: Of course not, you need to understand this: js code can only run as long as the user is on the page. If he closes the page the code stops. Client side language runs **client side** on the client's browser when he opens the page

Comment: ok thanks for your support...

Comment: do you understand what I'm telling you? if you want I can explain again ;)

Comment: I use to know of a site that use to do that in such a way that when the number starts counting if you close the browser for even after 2 weeks, by the time the user logs in the number would have increased and passed the numbers it was before. although they used php, but i just want to know whats behind it. Right now i can get the numbers to increment but each time i refresh the page or close the browser it starts from 0 again.

Comment: As I said, you need to understand how those things work. Your JS code can run and count as long as the user has his page open. If the page closes obviously the code will stop, therefore when opened again the code will not resume!!! It will run the code from the start (in your case start at 0). See, it's the client who's running your code. For a continuous counter, you need to save his count value when he closes/refreshed the window right? And that's done with FORM submissions or AJAX either ways you're sending data to PHP, from there you can save the data received in a database on your server.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to this is **[toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)**, which you can use to ensure that it only ever uses four decimal places. This is done with `nb_start.toFixed(4)` when writing to the page.

Note that you'll probably **not** want to use `toFixed()` if the number is greater than one, so I wrap it in an `if/else` conditional in my following example:

```js
$('#counter-block').ready(function() {
  $('.fb').animationCounter({
    start: 0,
    step: 1,
    delay: 100
  });
  $('.bike').animationCounter({
    start: 0.0100,
    step: 0.00005,
    delay: 2200,
    txt: ' BTC'
  });
  $('.code').animationCounter({
    start: 0,
    end: 570,
    step: 4,
    delay: 1000
  });
  $('.coffee').animationCounter({
    start: 490,
    end: 1560,
    step: 20,
    delay: 900,
    txt: ' cl'
  });
});

(function($) {
  $.fn.animationCounter = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      try {
        var element = $(this);
        var defaults = {
          start: 0,
          end: null,
          step: 1,
          delay: 1000,
          txt: ""
        }
        var settings = $.extend(defaults, options || {})
        var nb_start = settings.start;
        var nb_end = settings.end;
        element.text(nb_start + settings.txt);
        var counter = function() {
          // Definition of conditions of arrest
          if (nb_end != null && nb_start >= nb_end) {
            return;
          }
          // incrementation
          nb_start = nb_start + settings.step;
          // display
          if (nb_start < 1) {
            element.text(nb_start.toFixed(4) + settings.txt);
          }
          else {
            element.text(nb_start + settings.txt);
          }
        }
        // Timer
        // Launches every "settings.delay"
        setInterval(counter, settings.delay);
      } catch (e) {
        alert(e + ' at line ' + e.lineNumber);
      }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main">
  <div class="intro">
    <h1 class="title-plugin">animationCounter.js</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="block-wrapper">
    <div class="block">
      <p><span class="lnr lnr-heart"></span></p>
      <p class="counter-wrapper"><span class="fb"></span></p>
      <p class="text-block">like</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <p><span class="lnr lnr-code"></span></p>
      <p class="counter-wrapper"><span class="code"></span></p>
      <p class="text-block">code</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <p><span class="lnr lnr-bicycle"></span></p>
      <p class="counter-wrapper"><span class="bike"></span></p>
      <p class="text-block">bicycle</p>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <p><span class="lnr lnr-history"></span></p>
      <p class="counter-wrapper"><span class="coffee"></span></p>
      <p class="text-block">coffee</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>Copyright (c) 2017 <a href="http://www.pixel-renaissance.com">Micheline Pavadé</a></p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

To store the value so that the user doesn't have to refresh the page, you're looking for either **[cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)**, or preferably, [**localStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Store the variables at the desired point with `localStorage.setItem('variable', 'value');`, and then **set** the variables as the values stored in localStorage when the user visit the page again: `var stored_value = localStorage.getItem('variable');`.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I think this will only save the number then continue it back from where the user left it. what i meant was that is it possible for the number to continue counting while the user logs out or sleep for a day. For example the user launches the page today and the count started from 0 to 100, the user left the page from 100 and when he came back it has already gotten to 200. Hope you get me?

Comment: That's **semi**-possible. See my paragraph below the snippet, about `cookies` and `localStorage`. Both of those will persist **between** sessions, meaning that if you set a `localStorage` value on day 1, leave the app for the day, then come back, it will still hold the value. Simply set a `localStorage` variable to represent your value, and make sure to also **update** `localStorage` at a desired point. **HOWEVER**, it has to be set at a 'logical' point such as an amount; you can't be **certain** when a user leaves a page, so it's unsafe to code logic specifically around a user leaving a page.